# Preventing svn from killing entire jenkins workspace upon update

Tags: svn, grails, jenkins

I've got a grails 1.3.8 project that I am trying to automate testing for using jenkins. I am also trying to use jenkin's svn plugin and that is where the problem begins. For whatever reason the plugins of my grails project are difficult to pickup and normally require running the application a couple of times to get them all (bad I know, but not something I can change). I can get the project to work in jenkins if I get the plugins manually running the following command for each plugin;

```
grails install-plugin $PLUGINNAME
```

I want my project to poll our svn repo naturally. However even when using the option;

```
Use 'svn update' as much as possible
```

svn totally steps on the entire workspace killing everything, including the plugins which causes the build to fail because it can never manage to grab them all from one go of svn. I've been struggling with this for days and have also tried the jenkins advanced command

```
    SCM checkout retry count : 5
```

but that doesn't "seem" to change the build's results at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jenkins Config detailed (screen shot was coming out too small to read)

```
Advanced
Retry Count
SCM checkout retry count: 5

Source Code Management
Subversion
Repo URL : http://$IP/$MYAPP
Check out strategy: Use 'svn update' as much as possible
Repository Browser: Auto

Build
Build With Grails
Grails Installation: Grails 1.3.8*
Non Interactive: True (checked)
Targets: "test-app -unit"
server.port: 9144
grails.project.work.dir: target
Project Base Dir: ./app-api**
```

*Grails 1.3.8 is specified in my version of jenkins under the manage jenkins tab. But I have tested and verified it is setup correctly.

** points to the location of my project's api. This is the grails project I want to test which is inside of the jenkin's workspace, but not the only thing in it. That is why I specify it here.

Comment: Can you post your job configuration? How your build triggers is configured?

Comment: Added my jenkins config above. Only thing left out was the project name.

Comment: Adding the target refresh-dependencies before running tests didn't help?

Comment: If you build manually, running the process more than once, the plugin dependency is solved?

Comment: yeah manually I just have to run the grails command a couple of times and eventually all the plugins are picked up.

Comment: So a potential work around is to add grails build steps to pick-up the plugins. However these also can get an unresolved dependency issue which brings the build to a halt. Is there anyway to get jenkins to ignore errors in grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the Grails 2.x and not have this type of issue on solving plugins dependencies.

Looking for a solution in Jenkins I found the [naginator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) plugin that:

> allows you to automatically reschedule a build after a build failure.
>   This can be useful in several cases, including:
>
> The build is dependent upon external resources, that were temporarily
>   unavailable (DB down, network down, website down, etc). 
>   Users want continuous emails sent out until the build is fixed, in order to
>   prompt people into action.

I'm not tested but I think you will be allowed to automatically retry the build until it succeed.

Comment: This plugin was a good find! It would have solved the problem except that each time the project is re-built with naginator svn kills the workspace (thus any installed plugins) so the project just fails for infinity starting at the same place each time. If I take out the svn stuff naginator and the project work.

Comment: Everything under project/workspace is removed and a fresh copy is checked out from svn. Only stuff above the workspace such as builds, config.xml nextBuildNumber and svnexternals.txt remain.

Comment: Weird considering your "Check out strategy" be "svn update". What happens if you change to "Use 'svn update' as much as possible, with svn revert before update"?

Comment: I changed checkout strategy to "Always Check out a fresh copy". I didn't want to do this (And also thought I had already tried it), but atm the builds are working with this different strat. Sorry on the late reply I got pulled off this project for about 3 weeks :P